# Split string before date (d/m/Y)

Tags: javascript, angular, string

I am reading the content of a file and want to display it in an elegant way. Initially I split text using `split('\n')`, but somewhere in that file I have multi-lines text and that text is also splitting with this approach which I don't want. So I found a trick, I am going to split text with date, please have a look at below example and suggest me how can I do this?

```
12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User1: Here is a line of code 12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User2: Here is multi-line of code written in this line
```

As you can see in above example, every line is preceding with a date like `12/10/18`. So I want to split lines before the date. So it would be

1. `12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User1: Here is a line of code`
2. `12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User2: Here is multi-line of code written in this line.`

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes, I have had success splitting with /r/n depending on a few things.

Comment: looks like RegExp  can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text = "12/1/18, 10:33 AM - User1: Here is a line of code 2/10/18, 10:33 AM - User2: Here is multi-line of code written in this line 12/10/18, 10:33 AM A third line\nThis comes after a line break";
var pattern = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/g;

// Get the start indices of the pattern matches
var indices = []
while ((match = pattern.exec(text)) !== null) {
    indices.push(match.index);
}

// Split the string
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    str = text.slice(indices[i], indices[i + 1]);
    result.push(str);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is this valid for multi line text? for example if second segment has 3 lines. In my example where I wrote _Here is multi-line of code written in this line_ it means there might be more then one line of text. Hope it make sense to you

Comment: this function has done a great job but in some cases, date format is like this 9/13/17, 15/7/18 like this, In your code pattern is mm/dd/yy but how to add (m/d/yy and mm/d/yy) these kinds of format too?

Comment: @NeerajSharma I modified the regular expression so that it now also matches the other date formats you mentioned.

Comment: @NeerajSharma To your first question: Yes, that's why I added a third line to your example text that contains a line break (\n), to demonstrate that that also works. The text is only split at each occurrence of the pattern (mm/dd/yy, m/dd/yy etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You may split using a date pattern:

```js
var str = "12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User1: Here is a line of code 12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User2: Here is multi-line of code written in this line";

var x = str.split(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/);
for (i=1; i< x.length; i += 2) {
    console.log(x[i] + x[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: this does not work with multi-lines case as mentioned above

Comment: @ABOS May I have a multi-line example? I answered to the string reported in the question. Yes, you are right if a file needs to be considered, but how is formatted the file?  Thanks

Comment: gaetanoM , perhaps OP can clarify. I am just guessing.

Comment: @ABOS Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const str = '12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User1: Here is a line of code 12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User2: Here is multi-line of code written in this line';
const regex = /(?=[0|1]\d{1}\/[0|1|2]\d{1}\/[18|19|20])/g;
const result = str.split(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have 2 parts, you could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) using a "date like" pattern (Note that this does not validate the date itself):

```
(?=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})
```

For example:

```js
var str = "12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User1: Here is a line of code 12/10/18, 10:33 AM - User2: Here is multi-line of code written in this line";
var parts = str.split(/(?=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/);
console.log(parts);
```